# What is the meaning of "Unit of Work" concept in NHibernate and other ORMs?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, unit-of-work

What is the meaning of "Unit of Work" concept in NHibernate and other ORMs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is explained very well in [this blog post](http://nhforge.org/wikis/patternsandpractices/nhibernate-and-the-unit-of-work-pattern.aspx).

> "A **Unit of Work** keeps track of everything you do during a business transaction that can affect the database. When you're done, it figures out everything that needs to be done to alter the database as a result of your work."

Answer (score 3):

A unit of work is one or more database transactions that are either commited or rolled back together: either all succeed or all fail.  It's the idea of ACID properties for databases.